# Bluetooth keyboard dropping event on KEYCODE_ENTER

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth

I'm using a MicroSensys PENsolid HF bluetooth RFID scanner as an HID keyboard device with an android phone running 4.4.2. When I connect to the keyoard device and scan an RFID tag, it logs all of the `KeyEvents`, and then navigates me back to my previous activity. I've spent a couple hours on this and have found no relevant answers. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the relevant logs:

```
W/KeyDown﹕ KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_4...
W/KeyDown﹕ KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT...
W/KeyDown﹕ KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_E...
W/KeyDown﹕ KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_9...
W/KeyDown﹕ KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_1...
W/KeyDown﹕ KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT...
W/KeyDown﹕ KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_A...
W/KeyDown﹕ KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_F...
W/KeyDown﹕ KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_3...
W/KeyDown﹕ KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_8...
W/KeyDown﹕ KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_0...
W/KeyDown﹕ KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_0...
W/KeyDown﹕ KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_0...
W/KeyDown﹕ KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_1...
W/KeyDown﹕ KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_0...
W/KeyDown﹕ KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_4...
W/KeyDown﹕ KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT...
W/KeyDown﹕ KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_E
W/KeyDown﹕ KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_0...
W/ViewRootImpl﹕ Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ENTER...
```